# String is primitve or not? as for Spring framework

Tags: string

String is primitive or not as for Spring and how it treat as primitive or not? please help me?
this is my Code

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Serializable> entry : request.getProperties()
            .entrySet()) {
        if (ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper(entry.getValue().getClass())
                || (entry.getValue().getClass().equals(String.class))) {
            customHeaders.put(entry.getKey(),
                    String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how does that code relate to the question?

Comment: in Spring ClassUtils calls is there one of the method is isPrimitiveOrWrapper is checked whether given reference is primitive or wrapper by this case it wont work my condition for example if we take entry.getKay().getClass() it returns String by in this case iam bit confuse so thats why am asking

Answer (score 0):

In java, String is an Object and it is not a primitive.

References:
[Integer as primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099171/integer-as-primitive-type)

[Is String a primitive or an Object in Android or Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473488/is-string-a-primitive-or-an-object-in-android-or-java)

Comment: This should answer what you have mentioned in the title, but for the code part you need to give more input and post your question clearly.